# Plotting of data from infpy package

Tags: python

Following the documentation from [pythonhosted.org](http://pythonhosted.org/infpy/gps.html#).

I wished to plot only the points without the curve fit via the Gaussian processes and the background grey color which denotes the standard deviation.

```
import sys 
from numpy.random import seed
from infpy.gp import GaussianProcess, gp_1D_X_range, gp_plot_samples_from
from pylab import plot, savefig, title, close, figure, xlabel, ylabel

# seed RNG to make reproducible and close all existing plot windows
seed(2)
close('all')

#
# Kernel
#
from infpy.gp import SquaredExponentialKernel as SE
kernel = SE([1])

#
# Part of X-space we will plot samples from
#
support = gp_1D_X_range(-10.0, 10.01, .125)

# Data
#
X = [[-5.], [-2.], [3.], [3.5]]
Y = [2.5, 2, -.5, 0.] 

figure()
plot([x[0] for x in X], Y, 'ks')
gp = GaussianProcess(X, Y, kernel)
gp_plot_samples_from(gp, support, num_samples=0)
xlabel('x')
ylabel('f(x)')
title('Samples')
savefig('samples.png')
savefig('samples.eps')
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your the following line:

```
from pylab import plot, savefig, title, close, figure, xlabel, ylabel
```

To:

```
from pylab import plot, savefig, title, close, figure, xlabel, ylabel, xlim, ylim
```

After the statement:

```
plot([x[0] for x in X], Y, 'ks')
```

Add the following lines:

```
xlim([-11, 11])
ylim([-2.5, 3.5])
```